# Show that the following set is a basis for $M_{2\times 2}$ (the vector space consisting of all $2\times 2$ matrices):

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm not sure how to test for linearly independence when the vectors are written in this form? As i've only learnt how to when they're written like $v_1 = (1,0,0)$ etc.

$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0
  \end{array} \right]
 ,\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & 0 \\
     1 & 0
  \end{array} \right]
, \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & 1 \\
     0 & 0
  \end{array} \right]
, \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & 0 \\
     0 & 1
  \end{array} \right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

you have to proof two thing, (1) Linearly independence, and (2) this set generes. To the first, you do a linear combination:

$\alpha_{1} \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0
  \end{array} \right] + \alpha_{2} \left[  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & 0 \\
     1 & 0
  \end{array} \right]
+ \alpha_{3} \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & 1 \\
     0 & 0
  \end{array} \right]
+ \alpha_{4} \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & 0 \\
     0 & 1
  \end{array} \right] = 0$

And then you get $\alpha_{i} = 0 $, with $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$

For the second, you take any matriz of $M_{2\times{2}}$ and see that can be expressed as linear combination of your set.